# Linear equation with absolute value.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, absolute-value

Find $x$ if
$|x-|3x+1||=4$

I got 4 values of $x$ out of which 2 are obsolete... Why so??

Comment: What does obsolete mean for a value ?

Comment: They do not satisfy the equation

Comment: I dunno what they don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation implies $x - |3x+1| = \pm 4$. Two cases.

If $3x+1 > 0$ then you have 
$$
\begin{split}
x - (3x+1) &\in \{\pm 4\}\\
-2x &\in \{-3,5\} \\
  x &\in \{3/2, -5/2\}
\end{split}
$$
but only one of those satisfies the original assumption $3x+1>0 \iff x > -1/3$, so we end up with a solution $x = 3/2$.

Alternatively, $3x+1 \le 0 \iff x \le -1/3$, which implies
$$
\begin{split}
x + (3x+1) &\in \{\pm 4\}\\
4x &\in \{3,-5\}\\
x &\in \{3/4, -5/4\}
\end{split}
$$
Can you finish the problem?

Comment: Yeah... Thanks 